# How to split input string into multiple variable

Tags: arrays, shell, awk, ksh

I'm working on shell script and trying to split user input into multiple variable and use them at different places.

User input is not fixed so can't really assign fixed number of variable, input is separated by comma `,`

```
./user_input.ksh -string /m01,/m02,/m03

#!/bin/ksh
STR=$2

function showMounts {
    echo "$STR"

    arr=($(tr ',' ' ' <<< "$STR"))
    printf "%s\n" "$(arr[@]}"

   for x in "$(arr[@]}"
     do
       free_space=`df -h "$x" | grep -v "Avail" | awk '{print $4}'`
       echo "$x": free_space "$free_space"
    done

#total_free_space = <total of $free_space>
#echo "$total_free_space"
}
```

Basically $STR* variable value is filesystem mount points

Host output if run separate `df -h` command

```
$ df -h /m01 | grep -v "Avail" | awk '{print $4}'

***Output***
 150
```

Current problems:

```
(working)1. How to get free space available for each /m* using df -h?
```

Comment: It is not clear how you want to split. Provide few more examples to clarify.

Comment: @anubhava I provided echo as example, thanks.

Comment: df -h /m01 | grep -v "Avail" | awk {'print $4'}  --> give me 150, but this doesn't work in script

Comment: @EdMorton thanks, updated questions with what I used and what is the error and what I'm trying to resolve.

Comment: @EdMorton arr was typo, I fixed it. Error log points to line where I start `free_space =...`. My main goal is to  1. Check all mounts exist which entered by user, if not then exit  2. Get available free space at each mounts  3. Get total free space combining sum #2

Comment: @EdMorton I tried to provide all possible details with exactly how I'm running, also provided what output I get from server itself, not sue whatelse I can list here.

Comment: @EdMorton finally able to list free space with updated code

Comment: @EdMorton I'm sorry if you feel so, I did followed your suggestions but with small other change I was able to run this code to get free space. This is the exact function I'm running and error message text is the exact error. Updated code does work, there might be sometime small typo few places since I'm manually typing everything here rather than copy paste.

Comment: You show us the function but not where you call the function. You show us the error but not the line number that's producing the error. You show us the output of df+awk but not the output we need which is from df alone. You continue to use non-ksh constructs in a ksh script when you've been told about them already. OK, I updated my answer with the 1 line of code it sounds like you actually need to do this job based on what you've told us so far (which isn't enough to know for sure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest thing to do is to use shell array here like this:

```
#!/bin/ksh
str='/m01,/m02,/m03'

arr=($(tr ',' ' ' <<< "$str"))
printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"
```

**Output:**

```
/m01
/m02
/m03
```

To read elements individually you can use:

```
"${arr[0]}"
"${arr[1]}"
...
```

---

**Update:** Here is your corrected script:

```
#!/bin/ksh
STR="$2"

arr=($(tr ',' ' ' <<< "$STR"))
printf "<%s>\n" "${arr[@]}"

for x in "${arr[@]}"; do
   echo "$x"
   free_space=`df -h "$x" | awk '!/Avail/{print $4}'`
   echo "$free_space"
done
```

Comment: great it displays all mounts,  can you also please show me how can I use each of them to  1. check whether it present on server or not (`ls -l ${arr[0]}`), exit if not present and  2. Available free space. I get available free space directly from host like `df -h /m01 | grep % awk {'print $4'} sed 's/%//g'`  3. Total available free space from all array variable.   Initially I thought I will know what all elements will be there but if it's generated dynamically then it will not be possible.

Comment: added two spaces for linebreak but somehow it didn't work.

Comment: corrected as recommended, receives couple of error  1. for /m01 error: free_space: not found [No such file or directory]  2. for /m02, /m03 error: /m02, /m03 No such file or directory  (basically mount point doesn't exist for /m02, /m03 so trying to exit if such thing happens.

Comment: it was typo while writting here, edited that. I think there must be different way to use df -h within script.

Comment: `df -h /m01` give me 150 GB

Comment: try my updated answer, I tried to provide you a corrected script.

Comment: finally able to list free space with updated code, could you please suggest for question #2 and #3?

Comment: It is not fair to keep adding new problems. SO questions are for solving one problem at a time. Hope you remember original problem was to split the comma delimited arguments. You're welcome to open a new question after accepting this,

Comment: Since `df -h` accepts a space-separated list of devices, there's no need for any of that - one call to df piped to one small awk script is all you need.

Comment: @anubhava created another question as per your comment. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32726429/total-count-of-the-array-values

Answer (score 0):

you can try,

```
#!/bin/ksh
STR=/m01,/m02,/m03
read STR1 STR2 STR3 <<<`echo $STR | awk 'BEGIN{FS=","; OFS=" "}{$1=$1; print}'`
echo $STR1 - $STR2 - $STR3
```

you get:

```
/m01 - /m02 - /m03
```

Answer (score 0):

A variation on the theme:

```
# cat user_input.ksh

#!/bin/ksh
c=1
for i in $(echo ${@} | tr "," " ")
do
    eval STR$c="$i"
    ((c=c+1))
done

printf "\$STR1 = %s; \$STR2 = %s; \$STR3 = %s; ...\n" "$STR1" "$STR2" "$STR3"
```

Which gives you:

```
# ksh ./user_input.ksh /m01,/m02,/m03,/m04
$STR1 = /m01; $STR2 = /m02; $STR3 = /m03; ...
```

Hope that helps..

--ab1

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.sh
str='/m01,/m02,/m03'
IFS=,
set -- $str
for i
do
    echo "$i"
done

$ ./tst.sh
/m01
/m02
/m03
```

Don't use all-upper-case for variable names unless you are going to export them (by convention and to avoid clashes with built in names like HOME, PATH, IFS, etc.).

For your overall script, you should simply be doing something like this:

```
df -h "${str//,/ }" | awk '/^ /{print $5, $3; sum+=$3} END{print sum}'
```

depending on what your `df -h` output looks like and what you're final output is supposed to be.

Comment: agree for upper case comment, will change it. thanks.

Comment: Thank you for all wise advice, it does teach me various aspect of scripting and SORRY if I sounded like person who is not following instructions. :)