# Total count of the array values

Tags: linux, shell, ksh

Here I'm accepting few mount points from the user and using each value to get space available on the host.

```
./user_input.ksh -string /m01,/m02,/m03

#!/bin/ksh
STR=$2

function showMounts {
  echo "$STR"
  arr=($(tr ',' ' ' <<< "$STR"))
  printf "%s\n" "$(arr[@]}"

for x in "${arr[@]}"
 do
   free_space=`df -h "$x" | grep -v "Avail" | awk '{print $4}'`
   echo "$x": free_space "$free_space"
done

#echo "$total_free_space"
}
```

Problems:

1. How can I exit for loop if any of the user input mount not avaialble?
   currently it only add error in the log.
2. How to get total_free_space (i.e. sum of free_space)?

Comment: Have you tried anything for either of these?

Comment: doing testing on total_free_space, trying to use sum index and add with free_space and display final result, don't have any useful syntax.

Comment: Instead of translating comma to space, why don't you just put comma in `$IFS`?

Comment: Instead of translating comma to space, why don't you call the function with `./user_input.ksh /m01 /m02 /m03` and use `$*` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep your code , test this (no ksh here). If you don't care, read [Ed Morton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton).

```
./user_input.ksh -string /m01,/m02,/m03

#!/bin/ksh
STR=$2

function showMounts {
    echo "$STR"
    arr=($(tr ',' ' ' <<< "$STR"))
    printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"

    for x in "${arr[@]}"; do
        free_space=$(df -P "$x" | awk 'NR > 1 && !/Avail/{print $4}')
        echo "$x: free_space $free_space"
        ((total_free_space+=$free_space))
    done

    echo "$((total_free_space/1024/1000))G"
}

showMounts
```

#### Caution:

```
"${arr[@]}"
```

not

```
"$(arr[@]}"
```

Comment: tested this, free_space gets listed in KB instead of GB, total_free_space appears as 1.471390749074e+20G

Comment: It's not intented to be a full implementation (as I said, I don't have ksh), just some hint to go ahead. Don't use `-h` df's switch, because you dunno if it will output GB, MB and such. Start understanding and coding ;)

Comment: Thank you for your time and expert comments ;)

Comment: Use an editor with syntax coloration, errors like upper will be simpler to see

Answer (score 0):

As I said in [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32720995/1745001), you do not need ANY of that, all you need is a one-liner like:

```
df -h "${STR//,/ }" | awk '/^ /{print $5, $3; sum+=$3} END{print sum}'
```

I have to say "like" because you haven't shown us the `df -h /m01 /m02 /m03` output yet so I don't know exactly how to parse it.

Comment: if simple one liner works then I don't need any of that, my test program only has three requirements, 1. list space available at each mounts 2. Exit if any of the mount not available 3. List total count of all mounts.  `df -h /m01` gives me details of `filesystem  Size  Used  Avail  Use%  Mounted on`   `/m01` exists on server while `/m02` and `/m03` does not exist, I used them to generate error in the log

Comment: Don't **describe** what `df -h /m01 /m02 /m03` outputs - edit your question to **SHOW** what it outputs. I feel like I'm banging my head against a wall here as I've asked you to post the `df` output at least 4 times now. Maybe it's me and I should just surrender. Good luck.